# Binding DataSet to RDLC

Tags: rdlc

I am creating rdlc report(not using reportviewer, using report template). I have a business class which has a code for getting dataset by calling stored procedure. I am binding that dataset to rdlc report using ReportDataSource class. How to access this dataset in design?

In rdlc xml file, I tried to add dataset and it fields, it works fine if the columns are constant. I have a dataset it returns a datatable which has variable number of columns depending on user selection, will get to know number of columns at run time, that dataset I want to assign to table or any control in rdlc design. How can I do that?

Thanks,
Megha